# FutureBuilder and Snapshot in Flutter_bloc package

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

How do i implement futurebuilder and snapshot in blocbuilder by using flutter_bloc package. I am a bit beginner in bloc, so i need an example for futurebuilder in bloc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add more details of what you are trying to do. `FutureBuilder` is a widget so you can return it inside of the `builder` property of `BlocBuilder` like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder(
      builder: (context, state) {
        // here you should check about the state that is being provided
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: _future,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            //here you should check snapshot.connectionState
            return SizedBox();
          },
        );
      },
    );
}
```

Comment: I am currently using flutter_bloc and accessing the rest api from within the bloc. based on your sample code, how can i link the _future to the state of the bloc.